# Custom map style in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to create a  map based  android application. The question is How can i make google map a custom style? If it's possible then how to design a custom map style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MapStyleOptions` to customize the app using Json file,

```
googleMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.style_json));
```

You can generate this json file and put into raw folder from this [official site](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)

Read [this styling doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling) for Complete reference